# MUI: You have provided an out-of-range value `3` for the select (name="surface_id") componen

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem and I know what is but I can't solve it

I have the following select

```
<Select
    defaultValue=""
    labelId="surfaces-label"
    id="surface_id"
    name="surface_id"
    value={surfaceId}
    onChange={handleSurfaceChange}
    label={translation.word.surface}
  >
    {surfaces.length > 0 ? (
      surfaces.map((surface) => {
        return (
          <MenuItem value={surface.id} key={surface.created_at}>
            {surface.name}
          </MenuItem>
        );
      })
    ) : (
      <MenuItem>-</MenuItem>
    )}
  </Select>
```

and this is loaded with data that I get from the API using the useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!surfaces.length) {
      handleGetSurfaces();
    }
}, []);
```

The problem is when I want to edit and I add the following code to useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!surfaces.length) {
      handleGetSurfaces();
    }

    if (surfaceEditing) {
      setSurfaceId(surfaceEditing.id);
      validator.setFieldValue("surface_id", surfaceEditing.id);
    }
  }, []);
```

When is executed `setSurfaceId(surfaceEditing.id);` the data in the select doesn't exist yet because is getting from API and here is when I receive:

> MUI: You have provided an out-of-range value `3` for the select
> (name="surface_id") component. Consider providing a value that matches
> one of the available options or ''. The available values are "".

I need to setSurfaceId(surfaceEditing.id); after surface is loaded with .map but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Loading the Data

You are going to want to **use a Promise to call `handleGetSurfaces()` asynchronously** so that you can wait for the result before continuing into your `if (surfaceEditing){...`

This can be achieved with `async`/`await`, but if you try to use `async`/`await` inside of `useEffect()` you'll get this error:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFRR5.png]

This happens because **`async` makes the function return a Promise** and `useEffect` is not expecting the callback function to return a Promise.

An easy solution is to do this:

```
const handleInitialize async () => {
    if (!surfaces.length) {
      await handleGetSurfaces();
    }

    if (surfaceEditing) {
      setSurfaceId(surfaceEditing.id);
      validator.setFieldValue("surface_id", surfaceEditing.id);
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
      handleInitialize()
}, []);
```

What we did in the block above is that we called another function inside of `useEffect` and made *that* function asyncronous instead of making the `useEffect` callback function asyncronous.

You'll have to make sure that wherever you define your `handleGetSurfaces()` function that you make it asyncronous as well, so that we are able to `await` it.

---

### Using the Data

That covers the data loading, but we still have to handle everything property while we are waiting for that data to load. When the page first loads, the `<Select>` will be trying to use data that hasn't been loaded yet, so we need to fix that.

One way to handle this is to [conditionally render](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) the `<Select>` like this:

```
{
surfaceId !== undefined &&
    <Select
        defaultValue=""
        labelId="surfaces-label"
        id="surface_id"
        name="surface_id"
        value={surfaceId}
        onChange={handleSurfaceChange}
        label={translation.word.surface}
      >
        {surfaces.length > 0 ? (
          surfaces.map((surface) => {
            return (
              <MenuItem value={surface.id} key={surface.created_at}>
                {surface.name}
              </MenuItem>
            );
          })
        ) : (
          <MenuItem>-</MenuItem>
        )}
    </Select>
}
```

The `surfaceId !== undefined &&` says that we will check if `surfaceId` is *not* undefined, and if it that is true (if it is not undefined) then we will render the `<Select>`. This is called [short circuit evaluation](https://dev.to/harlessmark/short-circuit-evaluation-with-react-3dn4) since if the condition is `false` then the code will "short circuit" and not even read the next statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot, great explanation