# MUI: You have provided an out-of-range value `[object Object]` for the select component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-functional-component

I am trying to make a custom Select component with **single or multi select feature**

so I am initiating components like below

```
const vendorList = [
  {
    label: "John",
    value: "668",
  },
  {
    label: "Christopher",
    value: "552",
  },
  {
    label: "Liam neesan",
    value: "553",
  },
  {
    label: "David",
    value: "545",
  },
];

<SelectDropDown data={vendorList} isMultiple="false" label="Store" /> //single selection
<SelectDropDown data={vendorList} isMultiple="true" label="Store" />  //Multi selection
```

> Note: when I am passing `isMultiple = "true"`(can select more than one), I am not getting the warning. Only I am getting warning when `isMultiple = "false"` (can select only one)

Here is my **SelectDropDown component**

```
const SelectDropDown = (Props) => {
  const { data = [], isMultiple = false, label = "Default" } = Props;

  const [records, setRecords] = useState(data);    //data
  const [selectMultiple, setSelectMultiple] = useState(false);        //multi selection or not

  const [selectedMultiValue, setSelectedMultiValue] = useState([]);    //multiple value

  const [selectedSingleValue, setSelectedSingleValue] = useState({});  //single value

  useEffect(() => {   
    setSelectMultiple(isMultiple === "true" ? true : false);
  }, [data, isMultiple, selectedMultiValue]);  


  const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
  const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;

  const MenuProps = {
    PaperProps: {
      style: {
        maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
        width: 250,
      },
    },
  };
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    if (selectMultiple) {
        setSelectedMultiValue(value);
    } else {
      setSelectedSingleValue(value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {/* Conditionally Rendering */}
      {records !== undefined && records.length > 0 ? (
        <>
          <FormControl size="small" style={{ width: "90%" }}>
            <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-checkbox-label">{label}</InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="demo-multiple-checkbox-label"
              multiple={selectMultiple}

              onChange={handleChange}
              value={selectMultiple ? selectedMultiValue : selectedSingleValue}

              label={label}
              renderValue={(selected) => {

                // Render comma separated only if Multiple = true 
                if (selectMultiple) {
                  console.log("RENDER VALUE ");
                  console.log(selected);
                  const data = selected.map((item) => item.label);
                  console.log(data.join());
                  return data.join();  //output : john,david
                } else {

                  console.log(selected);
                  return selected.label; //output : john
                }
              }}
              MenuProps={MenuProps}
              defaultValue=""
              size="small"
            >
              {records.length > 0 && records.map((option) => (
                <MenuItem
                  key={option.value}
                  value={option}
                  style={{ height: "30px" }}
                >

                {/* Checkbox visible, only if Multiple = true */}
                  {selectMultiple ? (
                    <Checkbox
                      size="small"
                      checked={
                        selectedMultiValue.findIndex(
                          (item) => item.value === option.value
                        ) > -1
                      }
                    />
                  ) : (
                    ""
                  )}
                  <ListItemText
                    style={{ fontSize: "10px" }}
                    primary={option.label}
                  />
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
          <Box component="div">
            {selectedMultiValue &&
              selectMultiple &&
              selectedMultiValue.map((item) => {
                return (
                  <Chip
                    key={item.value}
                    label={item.label}
                    size="small"
                    sx={{ ml: 1, mt: 1, borderRadius: "10px" }}
                    variant="outlined"
                  />
                );
              })}
          </Box>
        </>
      ) : (
        ""
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

I am already rendering component conditionally, like mentioned [here(stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71918780/7734785)..

Actually my component is working fine with both single selection or multi selection.

But this warning is annoying me, when I pass `isMultiple = "false"`

What am I missing here?.

Answer (score -1):

The warning you are seeing may be related to the type mismatch when setting the `selectMultiple` state variable. In your code, `isMultiple` is passed as a string ("true" or "false"), but you are trying to compare it as a boolean (`selectMultiple`).

Here's your relevant code snippet:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setSelectMultiple(isMultiple === "true" ? true : false);
}, [data, isMultiple, selectedMultiValue]);
```

The `isMultiple` prop is passed as a string, and in the `useEffect`, you are comparing it to the string "true" and converting it to a boolean. However, when `isMultiple` is "false," it doesn't match the condition, and it might result in an unintended value for `selectMultiple`.

To fix this and get rid of the warning, you can update your code like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // Compare `isMultiple` directly with the boolean `true`
  setSelectMultiple(isMultiple === "true");
}, [data, isMultiple, selectedMultiValue]);
```

By directly comparing `isMultiple` with the boolean `true`, you ensure that `selectMultiple` will be correctly set to `true` when `isMultiple` is "true," and `false` when `isMultiple` is "false." This should help eliminate the warning and ensure the behavior aligns with your intention for single and multi-selection.

Comment: yes , I know that's a string and not a boolean, that's why I am comparing string with another string `(isMultiple === 'true')`, if condition true, it will return true, else it will be false. I agreed with your code for the simplicity `setSelectMultiple(isMultiple === "true");`, It will set only if the condition is true, other wise, it will have dafault value as `false`